# python remove "Next Line" Character (showing up as \x1b[1B)

Tags: python, list, line, element

I am pulling output with paramiko via ssh from a firewall.
The output is showing like this:

```
l = ['Total active sessions : 0\r\x1b[1BActive TCP sessions   : 0\r\x1b[1BActive UDP sessions   : 0\r\x1b[1BActive ICMP sessions  : 0\r\x1b[1B']
```

I was able to split the list with the following command

```
for i in l:
    i.splitlines()

['Total active sessions : 0', '\x1b[1BActive TCP sessions   : 0', '\x1b[1BActive UDP sessions   : 0', '\x1b[1BActive ICMP sessions  : 0', '\x1b[1B']
```

There is still appearing `\x1b[1B` in all elements in the table. I looked up the byte character and this appears to be a "Next line" character. Either way, how can I remove this from every element in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new_list = [e.replace('\x1b[1B','') for e in l]
```